# Virtual Subdomain with Username

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I use Symfony2.
I have an eample `site.com`. How can I do dynamical virual subdomain with username. When users logged in url showed `username.site.com`. But `username.site.com` equal to `site.com`. How can I do?

Comment: At least you have to add a wildcard DNS record: `*  IN  A  server_ip_address`, and a wildcard alias in apache's virtualhost config: `ServerAlias *.site.com`

Comment: You basically can't do this without creating your own DNS server. I use powerdns and mysql for example and I have previously created a system where I can add `A` records on the fly dependent on another database. ie you check the users table via a cron and create the subdomain for each user. You wuld then need another cron to ammend apache with the new hosts. Finally you would need to do a redirect on successful log in to the correct subdomain. This will not be easy and to be honest if you are asking this question you will likely struggle to achieve this.

Comment: My site is [CRM System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management). Subdomen is only fo image

Comment: How is the question linked to Symfony2? Once you'll have a working way to create sub-domains, using it from Symfony2 won't be hard. I suggest you to split this question in two: first create subdomains (remove the symfony2 tag), and later add a question related to Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you exactly want to do. But if I understand right, this may help you: http://www.devops.zone/webserver/dynamic-subdomains-with-mod_vhost_alias/

**EDIT:** I'm including the text and code from the above link:

For those using a development server for quite a lot of domains or those using some kind of mass hosting, not wanting to reconfigure each and single domain, this module might be interesting: mod_vhost_alias

First of all we need to activate the module which is by default included in the apache2 installation:

```
a2enmod vhost_alias
```

or by doing:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ln -s ../mods-available/vhost_alias.load vhost_alias.load
```

Then we need to create a corresponding vhost configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *.example.net
<VirtualHost *.example.net>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.net
        UseCanonicalName Off
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.net/subdomains/%1

        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.net/subdomains/
        <Directory />
           # directory options
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.net/subdomains/>
          # directory options
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Supposing that the server's name is example.net, apache will now lookup all subdomains of this domain in  /var/www/vhosts/example.net/subdomains/

Example:
test.example.net
will be mapped to:
/var/www/vhosts/example.net/subdomains/test

Of course this is not only working with subdomains, this is just an example.

Comment: Please include the relevant text and code in your answer, this answer may be useless if the link is broken.

Comment: In fact, I wanted to post it as a comment rather than an actual answer (as I didn't understand what he really wants to do), but I don't have enough rep to do this. I will include the relevant code and text but I think that it has to be moderated.